# c++ transfer matrix to procedure ,memory leaks

Tags: c++, matrix, parameter-passing

i am wandering. i can't believe my eyes! if i allocate matrix in procedure input ,  after exit from procedure, matrix had been deleted!

```
void input(int **x,int& m,int &n)
{
    int i,j;
    x=new int*[mx];

    for(i=0;i<mx;i++)
        x[i]=new int[nx];

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);   

    for(i=0;i<mx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
            printf("%d",x[i][j]); - i see normal matrix
}

int main()
{
    int **x,**y,mx,my,nx,ny;
    int i,j;

    input(x,mx,nx);   
    for(i=0;i<mx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
            printf("%d",x[i][j]); - i receive a lot of stuff

    return 0;
}
```

why matrix was deleted? as i understand, i transfer  **x , it points to part of memory , there matrix lies.  but when i have returned to main, i lost matrix, i have not deleted it. why have i lost matrix?

if i do this in  main   function

```
x=new int*[mx];

for(i=0;i<mx;i++)
    x[i]=new int[nx];
```

all is right

Comment: For every `new`, there must be a `delete`. You're *not* deleting - at all, hence the leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is passed by value to `input`; whatever modifications `input` does to `x` within itself, they won't be seen outside `input`. (Hint: try to `printf("%p\n", x)` inside and outside `input`). So, if you want to solve it with the least modifications to your code, you have to use a triple indirection here (i.e., `int ***x`) and pass `&x` to `input`. But this is a very C-ish way of doing things; in C++, you are most likely better off with defining your own `Matrix` class and work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
void input(int & **x,int& m,int &n)
```

instead of

```
void input(int **x,int& m,int &n)
```

i.e. pass `x` by reference instead of by value.

Comment: ha!   it works , void input(int  **&x,int& m,int &n)
  thank you

Comment: my outlook according pointers and ampersand is being changed)

Answer (score 1):

```
void input(int **x,int& m,int &n)
{ 
  int i,j;
  x=new int*[mx];
  ...
```

Where are mx and nx coming from?
From what I can tell, they are undefined.

Comment: i have forgotten write this, in this procedure   i do  scanf("%d %d"
,&m,&n);

Answer (score 1):

Change `int** x` to `int**& x` in function input.